# How to define class in and Arbre block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, arbre

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I would like to know how one can go about defining a class in an Arbre block. I tried to simply put the comma after the block, but Ruby accuses it of an error (specifically: "unexpected token tCOMMA (Using Ruby 2.3 parser; configure using `TargetRubyVersion` parameter, under `AllCops`) (error:Lint/Syntax)").

This is how I tried to do it:

```
div {
    h4 "Title", class: "title"
    span "Info", class: "info"
}, class: "my_div"
```

this results in the aformentioned error. But I don't really know any other way to go about this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbre definitions are ruby methods, that has a basic syntax that you have to follow. First comes the positional arguments, then keyword arguments and the last a block. In your example you do it in the other way around, so you pass a block then a keyword argument. To fix this simply change to:

```rb
div class: "my_div" {
    h4 "Title", class: "title"
    span "Info", class: "info"
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```rb
div(class: "my_div") {
    h4("Title", class: "title")
    span("Info", class: "info")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: I tested it and unfortunately it creates a problem. Now it does not recognize a variable I have from outside of it (I use this variable to get the data I want to display). But everything else works, so your answer is basically correct! So thank you

Comment: In the [documentation](https://activeadmin.github.io/arbre/) they mention this [context](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arbre/Arbre/Context) that can be used to pass locals to components. Also there is an option to pass instance variables in the controller, if that fits better your use-case.

Comment: There was no need, I found out that the second one you suggested worked!